# Find the Intersection of both lists and create new list that that contain elements according to frequency

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, frequency

If we have two lists:

```
list1 = [1,2,1,1,2,4,1];

list2 = [1,2,1,3,2,1];
```

then the new list contain the common elements or the intersection of lists and then the elements are added using frequency count:

**Result Expected:**

```
list3 = [1,1,1,2,2];
```

Solution I came with but it is not optimized

```
List<Integer> commonlist = new ArrayList<Integer>(list2);
    List<Integer> intersectionlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    commonlist.retainAll(list1);
    for (int i : commonlist) {
        int freq1 = Collections.frequency(list1, i);
        // System.out.println("list1: " + i + " -> " + freq1);
        int freq2 = Collections.frequency(list2, i);
        // System.out.println("list2: " + i + " -> " + freq2);
        if (freq1 < freq2) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= freq1; j++) {
                intersectionlist.add(i);
            }
        } else {
            for (int j = 1; j <= freq2; j++) {
                intersectionlist.add(i);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(intersectionlist);
```

Comment: Give more info on what you have already code, so we will be able to help you.

Comment: Where are "3" , "4" ? What happened?

Comment: @Lounis   I can't think of any approach

Comment: @Nick   We don't need 3 and 4 as they are not common element in both of list

Comment: use a nested for loop to iterate over both lists and keep removing common elements and store in the third list.

Comment: @akshayapandey   then how we will maintain frequency count order

Comment: @Lounis     Added code if you want to check

Answer (score 0):

I have tried an approach, each time an common element is encountered we increment an Map that stores frequencies:

```
public List<Integer> getCommon(int[] a, int[] b) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> frequencies = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    List<Integer> sets = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i : a) {
        for (int j=0; j<b.length; ++j) {
            if (i == b[j]) {
                int frequency = (int) frequencies.getOrDefault((Integer) i, 0) + 1;
                frequencies.put((Integer) i, frequency);
                b[j] = -1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : frequencies.entrySet()) {
        int key = (int) entry.getKey();
        int value = (int) entry.getValue();
        for (int i = 0; i < value; ++i) {
            sets.add(key);
        }
    }

    return sets;
}
```

The result will be `[1, 1, 1, 2, 2]`

Comment: Your Output is wrong as it should only return 3 ones's as list2 have only 3  ones lowest of frequency should be considered

Comment: Ok i have fixed it now, i replace encounter item by `-1`, it's a workaround (i'm from php  ) to consider lower frequency.

Comment: can you explain what have you done in double for loop

Comment: First nested `for` loops are used to create an map that store frequencies of each value, second `for` loop is not necessary but is used to create the final list as you wanted `list3 = [1,1,1,2,2];` but it's not an array it's `List` of `Integer`, by the way for each value we get its frequency, then we can fill final `List`.